# Cannot import Image to test Scikit learn application

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I'm a novice programmer with Scikit learn so my question is a basic one. I created my first Machine learning code programme with sketch dataset for object recognizing between apple and banana sketches and it works just fine in term of training and testing.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#loading datasets
apples_Full = np.load('dataset/apple.npy')
bananas_Full = np.load('dataset/banana.npy')

N_Samples = 1000
test_Number = 0.2
APPLE = 0
BANANA = 1

def normalize(data):
    return np.interp(data , [0 , 255] , [-1 , 1])

apples = apples_Full[:N_Samples]
bananas = bananas_Full[:N_Samples]
dataset = np.concatenate((apples , bananas))
dataset = normalize(dataset)
labels = [APPLE] * N_Samples + [BANANA] * N_Samples
#spliting data
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = tts(dataset , labels ,test_size = test_Number)

alg = SVC()
alg.fit(x_train , y_train)
preds = alg.predict(x_test)
Result = accuracy_score(y_test , preds)
print(Result)
```

Now I want to input an sketch image in order to use it as an object recognition application. I tried to import an image and converting it into a .npy file and use it as dataset just like test step but i got error :
X.shape[1] = 151875 should be equal to 784, the number of features at training time

```
testfile = "My_test.jpg"
Image = cv.imread(testfile)
TEST = np.array(Image , dtype = 'uint8')
np.save('My_test' + '.npy' , TEST)
Sketch = np.load('My_test.npy')
Sketch = np.reshape(Sketch, (1 , -1))
Testdata = normalizer(Sketch)
finaltest = alg.predict(Testdata)
print(finaltest)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did the below solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the error I think the shape of your input during inference is different from the shape of the image that you used during model training. You have used images of size `28*28` during training by feeding in the image of a different size during inference, you just need to `resize` your test images as shown below:

```
testfile = "My_test.jpg"
Image = cv.imread(testfile)
Image = cv.resize(Image,(28,28))  # will convert your image to 28*28
TEST = np.array(Image , dtype = 'uint8')
```

Also, if you are trying to normalize your data you can just divide the entire image by `255` instead of using `np.interp`, something like this:

```
Image = Image/255.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond!
I used your code in my program but when i want to implement my algorithm on it in the line:

alg.predict (TEST) .

I got this Value error : Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: I think it might be because my database is made of sketches which don't have color dimension. although my TEST Image was a sketch but it wasn't 2d and it has third dim. I wonder to know how.

Comment: You can just use `np.squeeze(TEST)` to remove the extra third dimension.

Comment: Tried This still got the same Error :(